# Firestore: Query a collection for all documents user has access to

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Running into a situation that I'm unclear has a clean solution.

In Firestore, I have a collection in which user are only allowed to access certain documents. Users can be assigned to one or more accounts, and Accounts can have one or more user. The general models and rules work as expected:

```
USER: {
  id       : abc123,
  accounts : [ xyz789, ... ]
}

ACCOUNT: {
  id      : xyz789,
  users   : [ abc123, ... ]
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /accounts/{accountID} {
      allow read, write: if accountID in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.accounts;
    }
  }
}
```

From what I can tell with the Firebase Rule Simulator, the above rule is working correctly (I can read/update the accounts that list my userID, but not the ones that don't).

The issue is that if I want to get those same accounts via a Query operator, I get an error. The error does go away when I relax the ruleset, but that's not ideal.

```
firestore.collection('accounts').where('users', 'array-contains', userID)

ERROR: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

Given that the ruleset and the query seem to refer to the same records, is there a way to get them to work in conjunction or am I forced to relax the rules in order to get this to work?

Comment: You can find a section called "rules are not filters" in the Firestore docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters 

I know this is a bit counter intuitive. But according to some of their videos, they do that for performance reason. Because that way they don't need to query the data, to know if you are allowed to read it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before and I found that Firebase doesn't check the fetched data to validate the rules, but it compare the **query** code with the **rules**, and depending on that it throws the exception

So what I found is that **the `if` condition should have a `where` filter in the code**

This `if` condition is missing a `where`

```
allow read, write: if accountID in ...
```

To make your code work, it would need to add a `where` filter that refers to `accountID`

```
firestore().collection('accounts')
    .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', accounts) //accounts: ['xyz789']
    .where('users', 'array-contains', userID)
```